# ERROR WHILE DEPLOYING MERN APP ON HEROKU, node and npm version is fine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, mern

Here is log file am using mongodb database
frontend is in root folder where as backend is in backend folder.
please help me fixing this error

````
sh: 1: run: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! login@0.1.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install npm && run build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the login@0.1.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.rKjZV/_logs/2021-06-17T18_12_28_684Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed

```
````

Answer (score 0):

The shell script `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install npm && run build` is equivalent to:

- `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`
- `npm install npm`
- `run build`

I assume you intend to run `npm run build`, for which you would need to set `heroku-postbuild` to: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install npm && npm run build`. Note the added `npm` after `&&`.